# Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest cannot be found in the navigation graph Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

**My nav graph**

```
composable(route = Screen.HomeScreen.route){
navigateToProfileScreen = { userId: String, userName: String, userAddress: String, userPhone: String, userProfileImage: String ->
                              navController.navigate(
                                  Screen.ProfileScreen.withArgs
                                      (
                                      userId,userName,userAddress,userPhone,userProfileImage
                                  ))

composable(
            route = Screen.ProfileScreen.route + "/{userProfileId}/{userProfileName}/{userProfileAddress}/{userProfilePhone}/{CurrentUserProfileImage}",
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument(name = "userProfileId"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(name = "userProfileName"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(name = "userProfileAddress"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(name = "userProfilePhone"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                },
                navArgument(name = "CurrentUserProfileImage"){
                    type = NavType.StringType
                }
            ),
            enterTransition = { _, _ ->
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(500)
                )
            },
            exitTransition = { _, _ ->
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(500)
                )
            }

        ) { entry ->
            UserProfile(userId = entry.arguments!!.getString("userProfileId")!!,
                userName = entry.arguments!!.getString("userProfileName")!!,
                userAddress = entry.arguments!!.getString("userProfileAddress")!!,
                userPhone = entry.arguments!!.getString("userProfilePhone")!!,
                userProfileImage = entry.arguments!!.getString("CurrentUserProfileImage")!!,
                navigateBack = { navController.popBackStack() })
        }
```

**Error Line**
Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/profile_screen/FBk4Nwq2/Ahmed /Cairo /01319/https://firebasestorage.googleapis03 } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0x442b361f) route=home_screen}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before passing an URL as an argument you must encode it, like this:

```
URLEncoder.encode(YOUR_URL, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())
```